# Can't affect carousel width

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

Struggling on changing carousel width.

The pictures of the carousel are vertical oriented so the width is way too big. Been playing with width (%, px, vh) and nothing appears to affect the width of the carousel. It's always displayed the same.
[image]

```
  .owl-carousel.major-caousel .slider-item {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .owl-carousel.major-caousel .slider-item img {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
    object-fit:cover;
    top: 0;
    max-height: 70vh;
  }
```

html

```
<section class="section slider-section">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="home-slider major-caousel owl-carousel mb-5" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">
                <div class="slider-item">
                    <img src="/../img/cover_up/<?php echo $product->name . $i . ".jpg"; ?>" alt="Image placeholder" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Making the width: 100% will only make the image retake its native sizing (therefore zooming). Also played  with `max-width`, `width` and so on.

Ideas?

Edit: Adding html.

Comment: could you provide a working example ?

Comment: Can you provide some more code, ideally an [mcve] snippet?  With the CSS alone there's not really enough context for your issue to be understood or resolved.

Comment: html just added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using owl carousel if am not mistaken so.

CSS code

```
.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Also in the carousel object change the number of displayed items to be 1

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
        owl.owlCarousel({
            loop: true,
            dots: false,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplayTimeout: 4000,
            autoplayHoverPause: true,
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 1, // make sure this number is 1 to display one item in the slide
                    nav: true
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hey! thank helped me to center the image (same size), yet the width of the carousel is the same. Only diference is that now the image is centered. Thanks, It's an advance at least.

Comment: MMM , I tried it again and it worked just fine to me... Also having the carousel in the middle is my own preference you should remove 

`margin: 0 auto; ` and see how it looks

Comment: also if you are using bootstrap as I'm seeing did you try `col-md-6` with your code ? it should make the size 50% of the row and that's will solve the problem ?

Comment: @FerToasted - if this user's post worked to solve your problem, don't forget to upvote them and mark it as correct.  Happy coding!

Comment: Well, It didn't work there somethig overriding rules whithin the code. Anyway you helped a lot. Thank you.

Comment: You are most welcome, and since there is something else overriding the code I can't help much without the CSS files. sorry, buddy. :(

Comment: Hey, found the solution. Using your solution in `owl-carousel.homeslider` solved it. Thanks!

Comment: So glad that I was able to help you. 